# How to use MySQL JSON datatype with Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js, mysql-5.7

I'm trying to use MySQL 5.7 with Sequelize, and I want to use the JSON datatype for the `attributes` field on my `users` table to keep track of user attributes such as home_phone, mobile_phone, work_phone, address and several other attributes/settings that every user may or may not have.

I've been able to locate the documentation for performing selects here: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#json.

I'm struggling to find documentation on how I would perform create, update and delete.

I guess I could always just do a raw query, but is there a sequelize way to do this?

**Update 1**

I'm specifically looking for how to perform a query like this in sequelize:

```
update Users 
set user_attributes = JSON_SET(user_attributes, "$.phone", "5554443333") 
where id=7;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Sequelize.fn](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#static-method-fn) method:

```
User.update({
  user_attributes: Sequelize.fn("JSON_SET", Sequelize.col('user_attributes'), "$.phone", "5554443333")
}, {
  where: {id: 7}
})
```